# Chrome and Chromium blurry images/pop-ups

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, chromium

I've had this issue for a while and I don't know what is causing it. This happens only on Linux.

Essentially some popups and images are really blurry as compared to other browsers.

Here are some examples, it might be hard to see on a screenshot but I can definitely see a difference.

Extension options (pop-up):

[image]

Quora notifications:

[image]

Regular images embedded into websites also tend to have this issue. Like for example these images I just embedded will look extra blurry on chrome compared to firefox or other browsers.

I tested `chrome-beta` `chrome-stable` `chromium-browser` and they all have this issue. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Also, I'm at 110% zoom by default but reducing it to 100% doesn't fix anything.

**Update
Disabling hardware acceleration in chrome fixes the issue. But I'd like to keep hardware acceleration so I don't know what is it about hardware acceleration that causes the problem.

Comment: Have you ever tried to test the chrome in incognito mode? maybe there are some extensions that force the chrome to change the setting.

Comment: @Woeitg Just checked, same problem in incognito with extensions disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so after some searching I found out the cause of the problem.

My nvidia anti-aliasing settings were set to `override application settings`:

[image]

Now I changed them to this and the issue is gone:

[image]